# I'm trying to decode a txt file with hex in it. I keep getting a ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 2 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I searched all over to find a solution but none of them worked.
Here is the code I have been working on python 3.

```
IPFS = open("Q.txt",)

Q = IPFS.read()

print(Q)

IPFS.close()

encoded = bytearray.fromhex(Q).decode()

print(encoded)
```

The Q.txt file has this string in it.

> 51

If you know what is messing me up I would really appreciate it if you told me! :D

Comment: what does `print(repr(Q))` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me with Python 3.9 i get the following output :

```
51 
Q
```

Are you sure you don't have something else in your file or i don't know... Try a Ctrl + A and delete all, and then rewrite your `51`

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me also on Python 3.8.5.  My guess is you have a newline after the 1.  Behaviour changed in version 3.7 according to the docs:

> classmethod fromhex(string)
> This bytearray class method returns bytearray object, decoding the given string object. The string must contain two hexadecimal digits per byte, with ASCII whitespace being ignored.

> Changed in version 3.7: bytearray.fromhex() now skips all ASCII whitespace in the string, not just spaces.